# Extract text using GREL in OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine, grel

I'm trying to add a column based on a column in OpenRefine using GREL.

I need to extract every text after the second space in scientific name.

Here is two examples of the original cell data ---> what I want to extract:

> Amandinea punctata (Hoffm.) Coppins & Scheid. ---> (Hoffm.) Coppins & Scheid.
> Agonimia tristicula (Nyl.) Zahlbr. ---> (Nyl.) Zahlbr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three ways to achieve the desired result on the given data, ordered from easy to understand to more advanced.

### Use column splitting

You can [split the column](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/columnediting#split-into-several-columns) into three columns by choosing a whitespace as separator and limit the number of new columns to 3 in the corresponding dialog. Then you can delete the first two columns and have your desired result.

### Use Array functions

You can use the same technique via GREL and [arrays](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#array-functions)... split on whitespace, discard the first two entries and join the rest on whitespace.

```
value.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ")
```

### Use regular expressions

You can also use the [match function](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#matchs-p) with a regular expression.

```
value.match(/\S+\s\S+\s(.+)/)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution :
partition on what appears to be a good separator : " (", take the right part and add a missing "(" at the beginning.

```
"("+value.partition(" (")[2]
```